# AWS - What is wrong with my Groovy Lambda Response?

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, groovy, aws-lambda

I am getting the error 
Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
Method completed with status: 502

i understand the response output for a lambda proxy needs to be

```
    {
     "isBase64Encoded" : "boolean",
     "statusCode": "number",
     "headers": { ... },
     "body": "JSON string"
    }
```

here is my class

```
class TestGroovy implements RequestHandler
{

   @Override
   Object handleRequest(Object input, Context context)
   {
    context.logger.log "received in groovy: $input"

    return [isBase64Encoded:false, statusCode: 200, headers: {}, body: " \"name\": \"test\", \"age\":12" ]
   }
}
```

Do i need to fill out every single header because i have none needed? Or is it most likely my json string for the body?

Comment: Have you checked CloudWatch Logs to make sure that your function does not throw exceptions or otherwise fails?

Comment: yep its super simple its just a test function, its something to do with this return line of code

Comment: should your keys in return statement be within quotes??